# JsonReader converting unicode characters wrongly

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am building an Android application and I have JSON data which contains Unicode strings. When receiving the data and using InputStreamReader to parse it, the Unicode strings stay fine. However, when I use JsonReader to parse the JSON, it appears to have converted it into some format. I have looked at the source code and it doesn't seem like it does anything out of the ordinary (obviously I might be missing something) - it just takes the string and saves it into a String variable. Does anyone have any ideas on why my Unicode strings are being converted incorrectly?

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code: what do you use as input to the `JsonReader`? How do you construct the `InputStreamReader`? Do you specify the encoding anywhere? *How* does it get converted incorrectly? What's the input? What's the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decode your stream to string using `InputStreamReader` and specify your encoding (e.g. UTF-8 or Unicode), then pass your string to `JSONObject` or `JSONArray` to create such object.

```
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));
```

Reference documents:

- http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/InputStreamReader.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: IIRC the charset is called "UTF-8" (with a dash).